# SQL Query that shows individual grades then a row that has a caption for the average

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem. Create a query that shows all of the individual grades for student 127 in section 95 and also the average of those grades. The individual grades should come first with the average at the bottom. List the grade type code and numeric grade. The average row should have a caption of, "Average for student 127".

I'm able to get the student's grade type and grade but having an issue understanding how to do the caption. Here is some code I have right now, I know its not correct but I'll post it here so you can see what I have.

```
SELECT Grade_Type_Code, CAST(Numeric_Grade as DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Grade
FROM Grade
WHERE Student_Id = 127
  AND Section_Id = 95
UNION
SELECT Grade_Type_Code, AVG(Numeric_Grade)
FROM Grade
WHERE Student_Id = 127
  AND Section_Id = 95
GROUP BY Numeric_Grade, Grade_Type_Code;
```

I'm assuming I might have to throw `COUNT(*)` in there to get the average? But even if that's the way of going about it how would I add the caption?

Any help would be great, also [here is the Schema](http://authors.phptr.com/rischert/documents/AppendixD.pdf).

DBMS: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Here is the Expected Result

```
GRADE_TYPE_CODE         GRADE
----------------------- ------
QZ                      92.00
QZ                      91.00
PA                      91.00
MT                      88.00
HM                      74.00
HM                      84.00
HM                      84.00
HM                      74.00
FI                      85.00
Average for student 127 84.78
```

Note: The Chapter this problem is based off of is consisted of

```
UNION
UNION ALL
INTERSECT
MINUS
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer so Oracle. I've edited my post with the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
-- vvv Setting up test data vvv --
create table #temp (thing varchar(50), grade decimal(4,2))

insert into #temp (thing, grade)
select 'test', 90
union all select 'test2', 95.5
union all select 'test3', 60
union all select 'test4', 80
-- ^^^ Setting up test data ^^^ --

select  thing, grade
from    #temp
union all
select  'Student average', avg(grade)
from    #temp

drop table #temp
```

Note in this example i'm creating my own test data, you could just switch out my temp objects for your real objects - especially since it sounds like this is school work don't want to give you the *full* answer :P

Comment: I need the "Average for Student 127" to be a row I edited my post with the expected result.

Comment: It makes some sense, I've never used declare and that doesn't seem to work in Oracle SQL Developer. I tried to just run your code to see but it won't run. I'l keep messing around with it though. Also to note this problem is for a chapter using UNION/UNION ALL/INTERACT/MINUS not sure if this changes things.

Comment: @OmniSquad should probably specify your DBMS in the future as that syntax would work for MS SQL :P  not sure what the syntax is for variable / temp tables for oracle

Comment: Yeah sorry about that added it to my post and will do for future posts!

Comment: @OmniSquad updated with a mostly complete answer it should work if your objects are switched out in place of my temp objects, though I don't have an oracle instance to test it out